# Java: Kind of list for highscore in percent

Tags: java, list

I want to create a list that holds a value and a name. The value is the percentage a player got in two decimals (for instance 0.94) and the name is simply the player's name.

I have this list:

```
List<Highscore> highscore = new LinkedList<Highscore>(Arrays.asList());
```

`Highscore` contains:

```
String percent;
String name;
```

What is the best way to sort this list so the highest percentage is first and so forth. I've seen some `Comparator` methods, but I did not understand them at all and they did not work for me. For instance:

```
if (highscore.size() > 0) {
    Collections.sort(highscore.size, new Comparator<Campaign>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final Campaign object1, final Campaign object2) {
            return object1.getName().compareTo(object2.getName());
        }
       } );
   }
```

Comment: "Did not work for me" -- did not work how?

Comment: Do you want to have items with the same percentage and different name?

Comment: Implement  `Comparable` in your `HighScore` to compare based on your percentage field. 
Then whatever collection you use, you should be able to use the `sort` method to sort.
`https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html`

Comment: I don't think this code could even compile, have you check the document of Collection.sort?

Comment: `if (highscore.size() > 0)` tends to be a micro optimization. You're better off letting `Collections.sort` be clever about it.

Answer (score 0):

Store them in a `TreeSet` and make the object `Comparable` with the high score being used to compare first and then name second. (Or use a custom `Comparator` on the `TreeSet` that does the same thing). That will have them in a permanently sorted collection.

Otherwise your example is correct except for the `Comparator` you are using which looks at name not score.

Storing the percentage as an integer (or float) rather than a String will make this easier.

Whatever you do you need a `Comparator` looking something like:

```
new Comparator<Campaign>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final Campaign object1, final Campaign object2) {
        int result = //Compare your scores here - however you store them will change this bit
        if (result != 0) {
             return result;
        }
        // If scores are equal then just return the result of a comparison by name
        return object1.getName().compareTo(object2.getName());
    }
}
```

The name comparison is needed as otherwise two people with the same score only one would appear in the `Set`.

Comment: Where should I put this piece of code? Is it a method itself or should it be put inside a method?

Comment: Use it as the comparator wherever you are doing the comparison - note that I didn't fully write it for you, you will need to finish the method. Look at the first comment

Comment: This could work, but I'd add a `timestamp` or `sequence` field so that two `0.94`s aren't equal and you get the expected sort order.